# Controlling for spatial confounding in point-referenced data

Tags: bayesian, correlation, inference, geostatistics

I have a point-referenced data set with 2 binary outcomes.
The data shows a strong correlation between these binary attributes - however, the geographic clustering is also qualitatively clear.
I would like to use a Bayesian approach (I thought of Gaussian processes) to find out whether the correlation is completely explained by geographic dependence (nearby points tend to be similar) or is in fact substantial.

So my idea is to use a Gaussian process classification model with a Matern Covariance function (with distance as the argument) to model the geographic dependence and try to predict the 2 binary attributes (4 classes).
My reasoning is that, if this turns out to work well on the test set, the correlation can be explained merely by spatial effects.

But I am wondering if this is a valid test for the hypothesis, since the correlation in my training set is quite high. Since one of the four classes is extremely rare, I cannot balance the training set.

I'd be grateful for any suggestion on how to properly deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are after a plot of correlation as a function of lag distance? If that is the case, an empirical variogram is sufficient: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variogram